# Distance Matrix FLoyd Warshall Python

Tags: python, matrix, floyd-warshall

To make a Distance Matrix for the Floyd Warshall algorithm "Shortest path" (https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/Floyd.html?hc_location=ufi), you need some roads as vertices and distances between these roads as edges. For example (departure, destination, distance): `roads = [["Philadelphia", "New York City", 120 ], ["New York City", "Philadelphia", 97 ],[ "Millburn, "New York City", 25 ],["Morristown", "Harrisburg", 150]`
How can I make this matrix in python?

This is the structure:

```
network[0] = #list destinations
for i in range (len(roads)):
      network [i][0] = #list departures
```

I don't know how to fill the distances in the correct position, because `network[roads[i][0],[roads[i][1]]` isn't the right solution when a destination or departure is used more times than one.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

If you have N cities you will need matrix of dimensions N x N.

First you have to map cities to numbers.

```
'Millburn' : 0
'Morristown': 1
...
```

Count number of cities - N and make empty matrix of dimensions N x N. Now set each entry of matrix (i, j) to  distance between cities i and j. If there exists no direct connection set value to infinity.

Once you have that matrix just run the FLoyd Warshall algorithm on it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for fast lookups, you could consider `dict` instead of list of lists (with a tradeoff of extra space)

```
distance = {'Millburn': {'New York': 25}),
 'Morristown':  {'Harrisburg': 150}),
 'New York City': {'Philadelphia': 97}),
 'Philadelphia':  {'New York City': 120})}
```

(take care of inserting the reverse edges and the values as well)

you can use `defaultdict` to create a dictionary like the one above from the array you've given.

```
from collections import defaultdict
roads = [["Philadelphia", "New York City", 120 ], ["New York City", "Philadelphia", 97 ],[ "Millburn", "New York", 25 ],["Morristown", "Harrisburg", 150]]
d = defaultdict(lambda : defaultdict(lambda:0))
for source,dest,distance in roads:
    d[source][dest] = distance
```

if you are using [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/), you can convert the above dictionary to a pandas dataframe.

```
import pandas
dist = pandas.DataFrame.from_dict(distance)
print dist
#               Millburn  Morristown  New York City  Philadelphia
#Harrisburg          NaN         150            NaN           NaN
#New York             25         NaN            NaN           NaN
#New York City       NaN         NaN            NaN           120
#Philadelphia        NaN         NaN             97           NaN
dist['Philadelphia']['New York City']
# 120.0
```

Comment: I'm afraid I can't use pandas... That's why I thought working with dictionaries was more complicated, because these are unordered and you can't select elements by index. And this is important, because I can't use for example "distance[Millburn]", I have to construct a general matrix, which works with every given tuple of roads.

Comment: @Materials, I've edited the answer to show how i created the dictionary from the array that you have provided. so constructing a general purpose matrix is not an issue. do elaborate if you need to use an integer index instead of string index; as that would be trivial to make.

Comment: @Materials, if you could edit the question, and also provide information on how you'd want to use the datastructure, then someone can help you with the creation of that datastructure